# How to deploy Angular + Laravel application on hosting?

Tags: angular, laravel, deployment

Hy. Can anybody explain me how to deploy `Angular` + `Laravel` application? I've created an app with `Angular` as front-end and `Laravel` as api, and now I'm confused about how to deploy my application. Should I copy all the bundles from `Angular` `"dist"` folder to `"public"` folder of `Laravel` app? Should I use `Angular` `index.html` in public folder or I should leave `index.php` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://medium.com/eliteng/integrate-and-deploy-laravel-5-and-angular-5-project-to-a-shared-hosting-8ce44050df91

Comment: UpVoted your answer too!

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the issue thanks to @GaurangDhorda article. It's really helpfull! But I faced some extra issues with angular/laravel routing. So here they are:

1. As described in the article you should rewrite `welcome.blade.php` view in `resource/view` directory to be like your `index.html` angular file from `dist` folder.
2. in `public` folder you also need file `.htaccess`, where you should place this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is required for your api calls from `angular` app in order to be processed by `laravel` routing (without this `.htaccess` file in response to all my angular api calls I got 404 - Object not found)

3. And finally you need to have one more `.htaccess` file in your root directory with the content described in the article above.

After these settings all should work as expected.

And one more thing, maybe not so important as described above. In order to prevent angular and laravel routing conflicts in angular app I set `HashLocationStratagy` provider in order to get /#/ in angular routes.